# Doob decomposition / stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stopping-times

Let $\tau$ be a stopping time, and let $X=M-A$ be the doob-decomposition of the super martingale $X$.
Proof that the Doob decomposition of $X^{\tau}$ is $X^{\tau}=M^{\tau}-A^{\tau}$.

So I know that
a) the Doob decomposition is unqiue
b) the stopped process  $X^{\tau}$ is again a supermartingale (Doob optional sampling).

can I use these information to prove  that the decomposition is indeed the one above?

Comment: Yes.  You would just need to check that $M^\tau$ and $A^\tau$ satisfy the conditions required of the processes in the Doob decomposition.

Comment: @user6247850: thank you, doesn't it follow from optional sampling that $M^{\tau} $ that is again a martingale? But what can I say about the stopped predictable process? What holds for this?

Comment: Let $X^{\tau} = M + A$ be the Doob decomposition of $X^{\tau}$. Use the formula $$A_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(E(X_{i \wedge \tau} \mid \mathcal{F}_{i - 1}) - X_{(i - 1) \wedge \tau}).$$ It seems to simplify to the requested formula (consider the values of summands on the sets $\{i > \tau\}$ and $\{i \leq \tau\}$).